# IONIC 4: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic4

Estou tentando obter algumas informações do banco de dados através da função `get()`, mas quando eu tento executá-lo, obtém o erro:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
  at HomeTabPage.push../src/app/home-tab/home-tab.page.ts.HomeTabPage.ngOnInit (home-tab.page.ts:18)
```

<sup>[Print do erro completo no console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTKv6.png)</sup>

No * `ngFor` já tentei usar o parâmetro Elvis, mas não funcionou. Já passei minha função principal de `ngOnInit` e declarei outra função para referenciar, mas não funcionou.

**Typescript/HTML**

```js
export class HomeTabPage implements OnInit {
  public advertList: Array<any>;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public adService: AdvertisingService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.adService.getAdAllList().get().then(advertListSnapshot => {
      this.advertList = [];
      advertListSnapshot.forEach(snap =>{
        this.advertList.push({
          id: snap.id,
          name: snap.data().name,
          price: snap.data().price,
          description: snap.data().description,
          image: snap.data().picture
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let advert of advertList">
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <ion-img src="{{advert?.image}}"></ion-img>
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
            <h2 >{{advert?.name}}</h2>
            <h3 >{{advert?.price}}</h3>
            <p >{{advert?.description}}</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

**service.ts**

```
export class AdvertisingService {
  public adAllListRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
  constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.adAllListRef = firebase.firestore().collection(`/adverts/adAll/adList`);
      }
    });
  }

  //cRud -> Read
  getAdAllList(): firebase.firestore.CollectionReference {
    return this.adAllListRef;
  }
}
```

Comment: E o que o método `getAdAllList` retorna? Porque pelo erro dá para deduzir que este método não está retornando nada, e por isso o erro quando você invoca o `get` nesse retorno.

Comment: faz sentido o que vc disse. Eu coloquei o código do **service.ts** para conferir. Eu posso estar deixando passar alguma coisa que ainda não consegui ver. Será que eu deveria passar algum parâmetro?

Comment: Essa função `onAuthStateChanged` é assíncrona, não é? A propriedade `adAllListRef` só será iniciada depois que esta função receber o retorno do Fire Base. Será que o problema não está acontecendo porque você está invocando o método `get` na propriedade `adAllListRef` antes mesmo dela ser iniciada? Outra possibilidade é a propriedade não ter sida iniciada porque `user` é `null`.

Comment: Depois que vc falou sobre o `user` ser `null` eu resolvi fazer o login novamente no aplicativo e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela luz! Eu vou corrigir um erro no `HMTL` que ao invés de `<ion-img src="advert?.image"></ion-img>` a imagem só apareceu com `<ion-img src="{{advert?.image}}"></ion-img>`